# Computer Powers Down During Sleep Mode

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I'm currently running a computer with Windows Vista SP2 that has begun turning itself off when it enters sleep mode.

- Memtest has had no failures
- SFC /scannow has had no failures
- Microsoft Security Essentials has found no viruses / spyware
- All updates have been installed
- No new software has been installed recently.

I'm at a loss of what to do and would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Is this a desktop or laptop? Check the power settings.

Comment: Has it always done this, or is the a recent occurrence? Does it do the same thing in hibernate?

Comment: Wasn't "Hybrid Sleep" introduced with Vista?

Comment: Desktop computer. Just recently started doing this. Haven't checked hibernation mode but I will. Power settings have not changed. Computer boots up before desktop with a "Windows did not shut down correctly" prompt along with a choice between various safe modes and regular startup.